# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup<any>' Angular 14 error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular14

I am a beginner Angular developer, I was building a todoList App using this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTn2nVphSl8 It was done using Angular 13. Where i am getting an error is in the todo.component.html , it looks like this

```
<mat-card class="mt-3 ">
                    <form [ formGroup ] = "todoForm" >
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 100%; ">
                              <mat-label>Task Name</mat-label>
                              <input formControlName="item" matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
                              <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
                              <mat-hint>Add task name</mat-hint>
                              
                            </mat-form-field>
                            <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" > Add</button>
                    </form>
                </mat-card>
```

and my todo.component.ts looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.scss']
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  todoForm !: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.todoForm = this.fb.group({
      item : ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }

}
```

As i was researching i found a lot of reactive forms being implemented using form control, i tried that method but it did not work. the error remained the same. How best can I resolve this. Is it that i am missing something in my todo.component.html or i am supposed to review the way i defined my form in todo.component.ts?

Comment: please share the error you're getting.

Comment: This looks weird: [ formGroup ]. Try removing the spaces there. Also, on what line do you get the error?

Comment: Hi, removing the spaces worked, the weird thing is it had initially flagged an error when it had spaces, but now all seems well. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the spaces in somehow cause the binding not to work as expected.
Remove the spaces, i.e. `[formGroup]` instead of `[ formGroup ]` in between the square brackets and it should work as expected.

```html
  <form [formGroup] = "todoForm" >
    <!-- Rest of your code -->
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may also occur in the following situations:

[image]

There you have to write: foncontrolName='password' !

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use the  UntypedFormGroup for form group type